# What does Hume think about Occam's razor?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, knowledge, hume, occams-razor

Let's define Occam's razor as this:

- That it is not rational to believe something unnecessary or extra about reality without a specific reason to believe it. In other words, the facts that are required or assumed by some explanation are unnecessary beliefs if you could have chosen some different explanation, which didn't have those same fact requirements but is equally consistent with what is observed; it is irrational to believe the explanation requiring more unnecessary beliefs.

Does Hume believe this personally?

If so, does he also assume it in his *Enquiry*?

If he believes it, does he think it is a relation of ideas or a matter of fact?

Comment: i am finding your question difficult to read/make sense of. maybe you should use quotes for the defitnion of occam's razor, e.g. the "[simpler](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Occams-razor) explanation of an entity is to be preferred"

Comment: @prof_ghost I wish to use, for the purposes of this question, the definition of Occam's razor that I typed. The question is just asking if Hume agrees with the statement.

Comment: the definition doesn't make sense to me. it could be that you just need to fix some typos

Comment: @prof_ghost What part of it? If I know, then I can edit to clarify.

Comment: "the facts that are required or assumed by some explanation are unnecessary beliefs if you could have chosen some different explanation, which didn't have those same fact requirements; it is irrational to believe the explanation requiring more unnecessary beliefs" seems to say that the simplest explanation is always preferable. maybe if you qualified 'some different explanation' with 'equally good' or replaced 'could have chosen' with 'could just as well have chosen'? anyway, i have no familairity with the question. just trying to help

Comment: Are you sure you defined Occam’s Razor correctly?

Comment: @MarkAndrews No. But I care about the definition I gave in particular (i.e., I don't mind if it's not really Occam's razor).

Comment: @prof_ghost Thanks I will fix it a bit

Answer (score 0):

**What does Hume think about Occam’s Razor?**

This timely article might be helpful: "The Philosophy of Security Risk Assessments," By Mark Ashford (13 November 2023); from https://www.asisonline.org/security-management-magazine

It turns out that Hume did not just use a razor; he had a whole guillotine! From the article:

> Another razor than can be applied to our line of work is that of
> Hume’s razor, also known as **Hume’s guillotine** or the is–ought problem.
> Hume’s razor is not too distant from Occam’s razor, and it asks that
> whenever we are piecing together information to reach an explanation,
> we should prefer the explanation that requires the fewest assumptions. (Emphasis in original)

Comment: What is called Hume's guillotine is IMO quite different from Occam's razor, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_razor. Hume's guillotine prohibits to derive a norm as a conclusion from premisses which all are facts, no other norm. Otherwise one makes an Is-Ought fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an agreed wording of the definition? If not, I prefer to call it the principle of parsimony. It is a philosophical tool. I do not know what Hume believed.